# How to query a DATE table using a shared ID to fetch a value from another column

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I am trying to wrap my head around a problem.

I have a product sales table which has columns for dates that match an ID to a date table.

I want to query the product sales table to bring back some important key information, but the IDs for the columns with dates are very useful. I'm trying to work out how I can convert these IDs to the full format which exists in the date table.

My structure so far is

Product sales

```
 - id
 - item_id
 - order_date_id
 - delivery_date_id
 - cancel_date_id
 - price
 - quantity
```

Item description

```
 - id
 - item_title
```

Date table

```
 - id
 - full_format
```

I'm trying to return columns for:

```
 - Order date (using full format)
 - Item title
 - Delivery date (using full format)
 - Cancel date (using full format)
 - Price
 - Quantity
```

I can join the product sales and item table to get the Product title, but I'm struggling to query the Date table and return a full format for all 3 dates. The IDs currently in the product sales table aren't useful. I've tried subqueries but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Maybe you want to know, that you can join a table more than once and on different conditions. So try to join the date table once for each date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SELECT` statement with `JOIN` conditions as below

```
select d1.full_format as order_date, i.item_title, 
       d2.full_format as delivery_date,
       d3.full_format as cancel_date,
       p.price, p.quantity 
  from Product_sales p
  left join Item_description i on i.id = p.item_id
  left join Date_table d1 on d1.id = p.order_date_id
  left join Date_table d2 on d2.id = p.delivery_date_id
  left join Date_table d3 on d3.id = p.cancel_date_id;
```

where using `LEFT JOIN` would be a better choice against probability for existence of non-matching records, and I presume `Date_table` has unique `id` column.